# CIS Firewall Issue

Tags: ibm-cloud

Finding it difficult on how to apply firewall rules for Global Load Balancer & DNS records managed as part of IBM CIS service. Unable to find descriptive documentation regarding that.

WOuld appreciate if we can get the help on how to address below concerns:-

We've enterprise plan for IBM CIS service & currently under a single CIS instance, we have 2 Global Load balancers plus 4 DNS records managed via it.

We have a requirement for below :-
1) To whitelist Global Load Balancers to be accessible only from the defined set of IP ranges 
2) To whitelist DNS records to be accessible only from the defined set of IP ranges 
3) TO Blacklist certain Global Load Balancers URL patterns

To us, it not clear how to use the feature "IP rule" or "Domain lockdown" , Examples or scenario based approach which explain the use -case of each these options would help.

Answer (score 0):

I am part of the development team for CIS. Can you please open a Support Ticket with the following information

1. CRN for the Instance and Domain name
2. Details on the Firewall Rules you want to add

> 1) To whitelist Global Load Balancers to be accessible only from the defined set of IP ranges
>
> 2) To whitelist DNS records to be accessible only from the defined set of IP ranges ----- Are you asking for Private DNS.
>
> 3) TO Blacklist certain Global Load Balancers URL patterns ---- Can you please give examples?

Thanks Vasu